# Multiselect two-column transfer widget with Twitter bootstrap theme

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am looking for a multi-select jquery based two-column transfer widget having a look and feel compatible with twitter bootstrap. Typically transfer select widgets have two adjacent columns where the user moves his selections from one column to the other in both directions. I've searched really hard but couldn't find anything remotely close to my needs. Can anybody suggest something (short of writing one from scratch). Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I decided finally to write my own from scratch. The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/rabihkodeih/bootstrap-transfer). The following screenshot illustrates the look and feel of the widget:

[image]

Comment: Pretty cool but it's too bad you didn't use Bootstrap for the look and feel instead of coming up with your own.

Comment: Actually, I've used it in a typical bootstrap app and it fits quite nicely.

Answer (score 4):

The widget that user698585 wrote is 99% of the way there, and is a great widget, but there are some bugs in it, namely:

1. The widget causes the webpage to jump back to the top whenever you move values between the two columns.  This is an issue if you have to scroll down to the widget.
2. The widget doesn't support  tag values with spaces or ampersands in them.
3. There isn't an exposed method to initialize the right column with values from the left, so if you're using the widget to store selected values in a database, there isn't a way to initialize the widget with those selections when the user returns to the page later on.

I've notified the author of the issues and provided sample code fixes, but in the meantime, if you've run into these issues, you can find a fixed fork of the widget [here](https://github.com/cdeyoung/bootstrap-transfer).

Thanks, user698585 for all your hard work!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a two-columns widget but has the same functionality. It's also a little prettier in my opinion:

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: So, that is "prettier" but it misses the point.  I love it for certain use cases, but when your list items have 30 character names (not by my choice), you end up not being able see all of the selected the values at one time, incase a user wants to unselect.  The two pane side-by-side

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiselect plugin [multiselect both sides have search functionality](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?qmi2lw8H)

Comment: the link is broken